# How does nature calculate instantaneously?

Tags: mathematics, nature

Physicists can make calculations about the world around us. However, it takes time for humans or even computers to perform the computations. How does nature do these calculations instantly?

Comment: It sounds a bit silly but nature naturally does what nature does.  It does not need to imitate itself.  Computers are trying to imitate another system. In some cases, you might be able to build an analogue computer that models the system without calculation.

Comment: That’s an interesting idea. It would be complex and very large, but could be very fast. Thank you

Comment: For example, a scale model is an analogue computer. A wind tunnel is an analogue computer for aerodynamic effects. Wind tunnels calculate "instantaneously".

Comment: Yes, that's the sort of thing that I had in mind.  More feasible in some cases than others e.g. a model of a plane in a wind tunnel.  Not so feasible for the solar system.

Comment: I thought information cannot be transmitted faster than the speed of [causality][1]? Unless this limit is what is meant, pragmatically, as "instantaneously".
  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causality_(physics)

Comment: What they said. *We* use calculations to *model* natural systems, but that doesn't imply that nature itself has to perform any calculations.

Comment: But this reminds me on an interesting paradox. If a physics simulator can model each of its own operations at a faster speed than the speed at which those operations happen naturally, then (with enough RAM) the "parent" simulator can run a "child" sim of itself that runs faster than the parent does (although I guess the child necessarily has less RAM than the parent). And of course, the child sim can run a grandchild sim that's even faster. Etc...

Comment: But does nature do calculations instantly? Some results have not been computed yet...

Comment: *How does nature do these calculations instantly?* What do you mean by this? Do you have proof or examples of this?

Comment: @PM2Ring, Re, "...paradox..." Sure, but all simulations diverge from the reality. Your prediction of the very near future will be almost-but-not-quite correct, and the further out you go, the further off your prediction will be. Digital simulations accumulate errors due to their limited precision. Analog simulations accumulate error due to noise.

Comment: @Solomon Fair point, but is it relevant if we're just simulating digital electronic circuits? I don't think we have to model them down to the nuclear level, or even the atomic level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think nature evolves according to some principles codified by the laws of Physics, written in the language of Mathematics. When you want to simulate these laws by calculation you employ your own structure, the "hardware", which is subjected to a latency connected to your abilities or limited by computer performance.